# Is there a tool (like SonarCloud) to check Flutter code quality?

Tags: flutter, dart, software-quality, sonarcloud

As [SonarCloud](https://portal.productboard.com/sonarsource/1-sonarcloud/c/123-support-flutter-dart?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InBhc2NhbC5nZWhyaW5nQG11ZWhsZW1hbm4tcG9wcC5jaCIsImlhdCI6MTY2MTIzNjQwMSwiZXhwIjoxNjYxMjc5NjAxfQ.0Ncwdm-iaOCcHnZHgcJfgBvB4utjlvpDWG4Cor1LID8) doesn't support Flutter/Dart I was wondering if there is an alternative for checking the code quality of Flutter projects.

Comment: Did you check this [https://medium.com/wriketechclub/improving-code-quality-with-dart-code-metrics-430a5e3e316d](https://medium.com/wriketechclub/improving-code-quality-with-dart-code-metrics-430a5e3e316d)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

These tools can be automatized to be used on CI:

- https://pub.dev/packages/dart_code_metrics
- https://pub.dev/packages/linter

Also there one some Github actions ready:

- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dart-code-metrics-action